# Можно ли использовать middleware для изменения response?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, fastify

Делается post запрос
Нужно конвертировать возвращаемый из контроллера ответ в XML формат(Сервис для этого готов). Как отловить и изменить response после того как он был обработан контроллером?
Пытался сделать это через middleware, но не пришел к рабочему решению

Можно ли использовать middleware в этих целях?

П.С. Внутри nest находится fastify